# MySql запрос (Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаю выполнить вот такой запрос

`INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_int(attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) VALUES (558, 0, (SELECT cpe.entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity cpe LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id AND cpei.attribute_id = 158 WHERE cpei.value IS NULL), 0);`
Суть запроса в том, чтобы занести в табличку catalog_product_entity_int все значения cpe.entity_id( а их там больше 1к), но чтобы поля attribute_id и store_id и value были одинакового значения для всех( значения написал в запросе)

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте фиксированные значения в селект

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_int (attribute_id, store_id, value, entity_id)  
   (SELECT 558, 0, 0, cpe.entity_id ...
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_int(attribute_id, store_id, value, entity_id) (SELECT 558, 0, 0, cpe.entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity cpe LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int cpei ON cpe.entity_id = cpei.entity_id AND cpei.attribute_id = 158
WHERE cpei.value IS NULL);`

Comment: такого плана???

Comment: Unexpected token. (near "(" at position , когда убрал VALUES

Comment: должно работать без values

Comment: Без VALUES работать *не должно*. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko Отсюда `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [(col_name [, col_name] ...)]
    SELECT ...`  даже без into должен

Comment: @splash58, Вы правы.